# how to make overlay close after user register

Tags: javascript

I am building an website where users are supposed to login before viewing website content. I try to do this with an overlay login form but the problem is I do not know how to make the overlay close after user press Submit. I think I need a JavaScript but I do not know anything about Javascript.

Can someone help me, please? Thank you!

This is what I intend to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>CSS Overlay</title> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
            html { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; } 
            body { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; font-family:Georgia, sans-serif; } 
            #overlay { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); width: 100%; height: 100%;min-height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 10000; 
            header, section,footer { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto 20px auto; padding: 20px; background: #ff0; }
            section { min-height: 1500px; } 
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <section> 
            <form> 
                <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/> 
                <label for='username' >UserName*:</label> 
                <input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" /> 
                <br> 
                <label for='password' >Password*:</label> 
                <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
                <br> 
                <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' /> 
            </form> 
        </section>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript 2 different languages. Learn it and come back when you have a more precise question on the code.

Comment: Can u Simulate the same on http://Jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Shikiryu: that was a typical typing mistake.

Comment: Sorry for not expalining well, I am new with this. I just want that the overlay close after user register. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is:
Add an onclick handler to the submit element

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

And inside it:

- Select the element you want to hide
- Hide it by setting it's display property to 'none'

In general if you want to protect your content it's better to

- Hide the overlay after the login is successful (so on some kind of successfull ajax callback)
- Not use JS/HTML to hide your content since it's easy to be found from tech-savy users

Comment: Thank you very much, Nickolay Ninarski. I am trying this right now.

Comment: The problem that might happen here is that after you click submit the form will refresh the page and no mather that you have hided the overlay in the end you end up again with the overlay visible. In this case it would be nice option to provide for the front-end a way to detect if the user is logged in which is implemented on the server side. So maybe add a class "logged-in" to the body

Comment: @NickolayNinarski right...So why dont you add that to your answer to make it complete

Comment: Thanks again, Nickolay Ninarski. I am trying your solution.